# Client server chat using named pipes

Tags: c++, c, windows, client-server

i have managed to connect the client to the server and send data between them but i can't seem to make them chat. Condition:- the server must print out the conversation, also the conversation between two clients.
this is my server code

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

DWORD WINAPI InstanceThread(LPVOID); 
VOID GetAnswerToRequest(LPTSTR, LPTSTR, LPDWORD); 

int _tmain(VOID) 
{ 
   BOOL   fConnected = FALSE; 
   DWORD  dwThreadId = 0; 
   HANDLE hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, hThread = NULL; 
   LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe"); 

// The main loop creates an instance of the named pipe and 
// then waits for a client to connect to it.

   for (;;) 
   { 
      _tprintf( TEXT("\nPipe Server: Main thread awaiting client connection on %s\n"), lpszPipename);
      hPipe = CreateNamedPipe( 
          lpszPipename,             // pipe name 
          PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
          PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
          PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
          PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
          PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
          BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size 
          BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size 
          0,                        // client time-out 
          NULL);                    // default security attribute 

      if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
      {
          _tprintf(TEXT("CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError()); 
          return -1;
      }

      // Wait for the client to connect; if it succeeds, 
      // the function returns a nonzero value. If the function
      // returns zero, GetLastError returns ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED. 

      fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? 
         TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED); 

      if (fConnected) 
      { 
         printf("Client connected, creating a processing thread.\n"); 

         // Create a thread for this client. 
         hThread = CreateThread( 
            NULL,              // no security attribute 
            0,                 // default stack size 
            InstanceThread,    // thread proc
            (LPVOID) hPipe,    // thread parameter 
            0,                 // not suspended 
            &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID 

         if (hThread == NULL) 
         {
            _tprintf(TEXT("CreateThread failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError()); 
            return -1;
         }
         else CloseHandle(hThread); 
       } 
      else 
        // The client could not connect, so close the pipe. 
         CloseHandle(hPipe); 
   } 

   return 0; 
} 

DWORD WINAPI InstanceThread(LPVOID lpvParam)
// This routine is a thread processing function to read from and reply to a client

{ 
   HANDLE hHeap      = GetProcessHeap();
   TCHAR* pchRequest = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));
   TCHAR* pchReply   = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));

   DWORD cbBytesRead = 0, cbReplyBytes = 0, cbWritten = 0; 
   BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hPipe  = NULL;

   // Do some extra error checking since the app will keep running even if this
   // thread fails.

   if (lpvParam == NULL)
   {
       printf( "\nERROR - Pipe Server Failure:\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread got an unexpected NULL value in lpvParam.\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread exitting.\n");
       if (pchReply != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);
       if (pchRequest != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
       return (DWORD)-1;
   }

   if (pchRequest == NULL)
   {
       printf( "\nERROR - Pipe Server Failure:\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread got an unexpected NULL heap allocation.\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread exitting.\n");
       if (pchReply != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);
       return (DWORD)-1;
   }

   if (pchReply == NULL)
   {
       printf( "\nERROR - Pipe Server Failure:\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread got an unexpected NULL heap allocation.\n");
       printf( "   InstanceThread exitting.\n");
       if (pchRequest != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
       return (DWORD)-1;
   }

   // Print verbose messages. In production code, this should be for debugging only.
   printf("InstanceThread created, receiving and processing messages.\n");

// The thread's parameter is a handle to a pipe object instance. 

   hPipe = (HANDLE) lpvParam; 

// Loop until done reading
   while (1) 
   { 
   // Read client requests from the pipe. This simplistic code only allows messages
   // up to BUFSIZE characters in length.
      fSuccess = ReadFile( 
         hPipe,        // handle to pipe 
         pchRequest,    // buffer to receive data 
         BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR), // size of buffer 
         &cbBytesRead, // number of bytes read 
         NULL);        // not overlapped I/O 

      if (!fSuccess || cbBytesRead == 0)
      {   
          if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
          {
              _tprintf(TEXT("InstanceThread: client disconnected.\n"), GetLastError()); 
          }
          else
          {
              _tprintf(TEXT("InstanceThread ReadFile failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError()); 
          }
          break;
      }

   // Process the incoming message.
      GetAnswerToRequest(pchRequest, pchReply, &cbReplyBytes); 

   // Write the reply to the pipe. 
      fSuccess = WriteFile( 
         hPipe,        // handle to pipe 
         pchReply,     // buffer to write from 
         cbReplyBytes, // number of bytes to write 
         &cbWritten,   // number of bytes written 
         NULL);        // not overlapped I/O 

      if (!fSuccess || cbReplyBytes != cbWritten)
      {   
          _tprintf(TEXT("InstanceThread WriteFile failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError()); 
          break;
      }
  }

// Flush the pipe to allow the client to read the pipe's contents 
// before disconnecting. Then disconnect the pipe, and close the 
// handle to this pipe instance. 

   FlushFileBuffers(hPipe); 
   DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe); 
   CloseHandle(hPipe); 

   HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
   HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);

   printf("InstanceThread exitting.\n");
   return 1;
}

VOID GetAnswerToRequest( LPTSTR pchRequest, 
                         LPTSTR pchReply, 
                         LPDWORD pchBytes )
// This routine is a simple function to print the client request to the console
// and populate the reply buffer with a default data string. This is where you
// would put the actual client request processing code that runs in the context
// of an instance thread.
{
    _tprintf( TEXT("Client Request String:\"%s\"\n"), pchRequest );

    // Check the outgoing message to make sure it's not too long for the buffer.
    if (FAILED(StringCchCopy( pchReply, BUFSIZE, TEXT("default answer from server") )))
    {
        *pchBytes = 0;
        pchReply[0] = 0;
        printf("StringCchCopy failed, no outgoing message.\n");
        return;
    }
    *pchBytes = (lstrlen(pchReply)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR);
}
```

this is my client code

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{ 
   HANDLE hPipe; 
   LPTSTR lpvMessage=TEXT("Default message from client."); 
   TCHAR  chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   BOOL   fSuccess = FALSE; 
   DWORD  cbRead, cbToWrite, cbWritten, dwMode; 
   LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe"); 

   if( argc > 1 )
      lpvMessage = argv[1];

// Try to open a named pipe; wait for it, if necessary. 

   while (1) 
   { 
      hPipe = CreateFile( 
         lpszPipename,   // pipe name 
         GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
         GENERIC_WRITE, 
         0,              // no sharing 
         NULL,           // default security attributes
         OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
         0,              // default attributes 
         NULL);          // no template file 

   // Break if the pipe handle is valid. 

      if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
         break; 

      // Exit if an error other than ERROR_PIPE_BUSY occurs. 

      if (GetLastError() != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY) 
      {
         _tprintf( TEXT("Could not open pipe. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError() ); 
         return -1;
      }

      // All pipe instances are busy, so wait for 20 seconds. 

      if ( ! WaitNamedPipe(lpszPipename, 20000)) 
      { 
         printf("Could not open pipe: 20 second wait timed out."); 
         return -1;
      } 
   } 

// The pipe connected; change to message-read mode. 

   dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE; 
   fSuccess = SetNamedPipeHandleState( 
      hPipe,    // pipe handle 
      &dwMode,  // new pipe mode 
      NULL,     // don't set maximum bytes 
      NULL);    // don't set maximum time 
   if ( ! fSuccess) 
   {
      _tprintf( TEXT("SetNamedPipeHandleState failed. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError() ); 
      return -1;
   }

// Send a message to the pipe server. 

   cbToWrite = (lstrlen(lpvMessage)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR);
   _tprintf( TEXT("Sending %d byte message: \"%s\"\n"), cbToWrite, lpvMessage); 

   fSuccess = WriteFile( 
      hPipe,                  // pipe handle 
      lpvMessage,             // message 
      cbToWrite,              // message length 
      &cbWritten,             // bytes written 
      NULL);                  // not overlapped 

   if ( ! fSuccess) 
   {
      _tprintf( TEXT("WriteFile to pipe failed. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError() ); 
      return -1;
   }

   printf("\nMessage sent to server, receiving reply as follows:\n");

   do 
   { 
   // Read from the pipe. 

      fSuccess = ReadFile( 
         hPipe,    // pipe handle 
         chBuf,    // buffer to receive reply 
         BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),  // size of buffer 
         &cbRead,  // number of bytes read 
         NULL);    // not overlapped 

      if ( ! fSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA )
         break; 

      _tprintf( TEXT("\"%s\"\n"), chBuf ); 
   } while ( ! fSuccess);  // repeat loop if ERROR_MORE_DATA 

   if ( ! fSuccess)
   {
      _tprintf( TEXT("ReadFile from pipe failed. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError() );
      return -1;
   }

   printf("\n<End of message, press ENTER to terminate connection and exit>");
   _getch();

   CloseHandle(hPipe); 

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: post minimum code showing where exactly you are having problem

Comment: i want to enable this program to chat between the server and the client...the server can connect multiple clients. but i need it to not only enable chat but also print out the conversation. thank you

Comment: Are you getting an error or just don't know how to do what you want?

Comment: i would like to know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

In order to map the participants of the conversation one method would be to use an address to alias mapping. You could use a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` for that. In order to populate the map though you need to provide an identification message first.

Another way to do this would be to include the alias in every message. To do that you need to define your own message protocol. For example you could base it on xml (and thus take advantage of ready-made xml libraries):

```
<msg>
    <src>Dave</src>
    <dest>Steve</dest>
    <payload>
        <b>HI!</b>How are <u>you</u>
    </payload>
</msg>
```